# Cardinal product and cardinal sum

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the case when we have $H$ and $K$ are two subgroups of abelian group $G$ with $H\cap K = \left\{0\right\}, 
 $$G = HK$ then we have $G = H\times_{c}K.$ Being $G$ abelian we can write $G = H \oplus K.$ This is the internal sum of groups.
When we have two groups $A$ and $B,$ then we define a new group denoted by $A\times_{c}B = \left\{(a, b) : a \in A, b\in B \right\}$ called the direct product of group $A$ and $B$ and the group operation is componentwise. This is the same as direct sum $A\oplus B.$ Let $x\in A\oplus B.$ Then there exists $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $x = a + b$ is the same as ordered pair $(a, b).$

My concern here is if we define new groups $G = A\oplus B,$ because of the uniqueness of represents of the element $A\cap B = \left\{0\right\}.$ When we have $A = B = \mathbb Z,$ then how do think this intersection idea is zero. The one idea here is we can think $A \cong\mathbb Z\oplus 0$ and $B \cong 0\oplus \mathbb Z,$ then $A \cap B = \left\{0\right\}.$ Is this the correct way? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the two relevant copies of $\Bbb Z$ inside $\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z$ are $\Bbb Z\oplus0$ and $0\oplus\Bbb Z$.